# Error: [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

```
String adminEmail = "";
  String adminPassword = "";

  allowAdminLogin() async {
    SnackBar snackBar = const SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        "Checking Credentials Please wait .....",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 36,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 6),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    User? currentAdmin;
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: adminEmail,
      password: adminPassword,
    )
        .then((fAuth) {
      currentAdmin = fAuth.user;
    });
    if (currentAdmin != null) {
      ///check if that admin record also exists in the admins collection in firestore database,
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('admins')
          .doc(currentAdmin!.uid)
          .get().then((snap) {
        if (snap.exists) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const HomeScreen()));
        } else {
          SnackBar snackBar = const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              "No record found ,Checking Credentials, you are not an admin.",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 36,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 6),
          );
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to authenticate the email

```
String adminEmail = "";
```

which is not a valid email, so firebase will not authenticate it.
you need to make sure that the email is valid.